# webView.evaluateJavascript. Doesn't want to execute.

Tags: android, webview, xamarin

Wrote some renderer for Android webView.
Tryin' to call some javascript like this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Kitkat)
            {
                this.Control.EvaluateJavascript(@"javascript: alert('asdasd');", new ValueCallback(() => { }));
            }
            else
            {
                this.Control.LoadUrl(@"javascript:alert('asdasd');");
            }
```

Before it I setted

```
this.Control.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
```

And there is no reaction. I can't see neither alert no any action in ValueCallback class. 
What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

add this :

```
Control.SetWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

it'll work.